# Eigenvalues of a Covariance Matrix with Noise

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, covariance, correlation, svd, symmetric-matrices

Imagine to have a covariance matrix $2\times 2$ called $\Sigma^*$.

\begin{bmatrix}1+\sigma^2&\rho_{12}\\\rho_{21}&1+\sigma^2\end{bmatrix}

I know that $\rho_{12} = \rho_{21}$ because it's symmetric.

I proceed in calculating the eigenvalues from

> $$\det(\Sigma^*-\lambda I) = \lambda^2 - 2\lambda(1+\sigma^2) + (1+\sigma^4+2\sigma^2-\rho_{12}^2).$$

and finally the eigenvalues are:

> $\lambda_1 = 1+\sigma^2 + \rho_{12}$
>
> $\lambda_2 = 1+\sigma^2 - \rho_{12}.$

Now I've tried to do the same with a $3 \times 3$ matrix

$$\Sigma^* = \begin{bmatrix}1+\sigma^2&\rho_{12}&\rho_{13}\\\rho_{21}&1+\sigma^2&\rho_{23}\\\rho_{31}&\rho_{32}&1+\sigma^2\end{bmatrix}.$$

I know that $\rho_{12} = \rho_{21}, \rho_{13} = \rho_{31}, \rho_{23} = \rho_{32}$ because it's symmetric.

Now I'm kinda stuck. I'll leave below what I did:

> $$\det(Σ^*-\lambda I) = (1+\sigma^2 -\lambda)^3 - (1+\sigma^2 -\lambda)(\rho_{12}^2 + \rho_{13}^2 + \rho_{23}^2) + 2 \rho_{12}\rho_{13}\rho_{23}$$

and if $z = 1+\sigma^2 -\lambda$

> $$\det(Σ^*-\lambda I) = z^3 - z(\rho_{12}^2 + \rho_{13}^2 + \rho_{23}^2) + 2 \rho_{12}\rho_{13}\rho_{23}.$$

How can I go further? Is it better to either find the values of z or to use another approach like SVD if applicable?

My main goal is to find those eigenvalues.

****** UPDATE ******

Following the answer below from @GNUSupporter 8964民主女神 地下教會, I see that since the discriminant is less or equal to zero, I have that

$u^3, v^3 = -\dfrac{q}{2} ± i\sqrt{-\Delta}$

their module is $R = \sqrt{(-\frac{q}{2})^2+(\sqrt{-\Delta})^2}$

Do I need $R$? If yes, I need to calculate $\theta = arctg (-\frac{\sqrt{-\Delta}}{-\frac{q}{2}})$

If not, is it possible to just say that

$$x = u + v = \sqrt[3]{-\dfrac{q}{2} + i\sqrt{-\Delta}} + \sqrt[3]{-\dfrac{q}{2} - i\sqrt{-\Delta}}?$$

Comment: Real symmetric matrices are always diagonalisable.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 uhm, ok. So, how is this answer related to my question?

Comment: Therefore, the characteristic polynomial of the covariance matrix is always [solvable in $\Bbb{R}$](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~jerison/math2940/real-eigenvalues.pdf), so you don't need SVD.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 so, could you provide me support in resolving that equation to find its roots?

Comment: I've posted a solution in response to your comment.  Please check.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 as soon as I get home I will, thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93064/discussion-between-gnusupporter-8964--and-jacklametta).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My main goal is to find those eigenvalues.

To find $\Sigma^*$'s eigenvalues, apply [Cardano's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano.27s_method) with $p = -(\rho_{12}^2 + \rho_{23}^2 + \rho_{31}^2)$ and $q = 2 \rho_{12}\rho_{23}\rho_{31}$ to your last equality

> $$\det(Σ^*-\lambda I) = z^3 - z(\rho_{12}^2 + \rho_{23}^2 + \rho_{31}^2) + 2 \rho_{12}\rho_{23}\rho_{31}. \tag1 \label1$$

We introduce variables $u$ and $v$ so that $z = u + v$

\begin{align}
u^{3} &= -{q \over 2}+{\sqrt {{q^{2} \over 4}+{p^{3} \over 27}}} = -\rho_{12}\rho_{23}\rho_{31} + \sqrt{(\rho_{12}\rho_{23}\rho_{31})^2 - \frac{(\rho_{12}^2 + \rho_{23}^2 + \rho_{31}^2)^3}{27}} \tag2 \label2 \\
v^{3} &= -{q \over 2}-{\sqrt {{q^{2} \over 4}+{p^{3} \over 27}}} = -\rho_{12}\rho_{23}\rho_{31} - \sqrt{(\rho_{12}\rho_{23}\rho_{31})^2 - \frac{(\rho_{12}^2 + \rho_{23}^2 + \rho_{31}^2)^3}{27}}. \tag3 \label3
\end{align}

Note that by the [a.m.-g.m.-inequality](/questions/tagged/a.m.-g.m.-inequality),

$$\sqrt[3]{\rho_{12}^2 \rho_{23}^2 \rho_{31}^2} \le \frac{\rho_{12}^2 + \rho_{23}^2 + \rho_{31}^2}{3},$$

so the discriminant $$\Delta = {q^{2} \over 4}+{p^{3} \over 27} \le 0.$$

$\Delta = 0$ iff equality holds in the AM-GM inequality iff $\rho_{12}^2 = \rho_{23}^2 = \rho_{31}^2$.

Observe from \eqref{2} and \eqref{3} that $u^3 = \overline{v^3}$.  Denote $\omega$ the third root of unity not equal to $1$.  (i.e. $\omega^3 = 1$ but $\omega \ne 1$.)

Since all eigenvalues of a real symmetric matrix are real, you just take $u + \overline{u}$, $\omega u + \overline{\omega u}$ and $\omega^2 u + \overline{\omega^2 u}$ as roots for \eqref{1}, where $u$ is fixed as any one of the three roots of \eqref{2}.

> It doesn't matter which root of \eqref{2} is chosen since $\omega$ permutes the three roots, so eventually, all three roots of \eqref{2} are covered.

To finish this question, just do the substitution $\lambda = 1+\sigma^2 -z$.

---

Edit in response to OP's comment

Despite OP's edit to include some trigonometric function, in this section, I shall make no use of them since this is essentially an algebra problem for finding [roots](/questions/tagged/roots) of [cubic-equations](/questions/tagged/cubic-equations), and that trigonometric functions are transcendental.  I'll keep my existing working algebraic at the first place.  By algebra, I don't mean to be arithmetic, that is, I avoid as much calculations as possible.

Each of equations \eqref{2} and \eqref{3} have three distinct roots, so there are at most $3 \times 3 = 9$ candidates for $z = u + v$.

> I say "at most" since I haven't (and won't directly) checked some of them repeat themselves.

The reason for \eqref{2} and \eqref{3} to have three distinct roots is that the cubic equation $\omega^3 = 1$ has three distinct roots: $1$ and the two conjugate complex roots $\omega$ and $\bar{\omega} = \omega ^2$, so that $\omega^2 + \omega + 1 = 0$.  If you fix a root $u$, then $\omega u$ and $\omega^2 u$ are also roots to \eqref{2} since $(\omega u)^3 = \omega^3 u^3 = u^3$ and $(\omega^2 u)^3 = (\omega^3)^2 u^3 = u^3$.  Since we want to represent all three roots of \eqref{2} as $u, \omega u, \omega^2 u$, we don't want $\omega = 1$.

To visualize $u$, you may consider it as a nonzero arrow on the complex plane, and $\omega$ as a rotation of 120°.

[image]
Third roots of unity
Image source: [Wikimedia commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:3rd-roots-of-unity.png)

Given that \eqref{2} is solved and that $u^3 = \overline{v^3}$, the easiest root for \eqref{3} would be $v = \bar{u}$.  Apply the *same* argument above to see that roots of \eqref{3} are $\bar{u}, \omega \bar{u}, \omega^2 \bar{u}$.

The remaining work is too select the three real values from $\omega^i u + \omega^j \bar{u}$, $i,j \in \{0,1,2\}$.  The easiest choice is the case when $i = j = 0$, so that $z = u + \bar{u} \in \Bbb{R}$.  It should be quite obvious that we should choose $\omega u + \overline{\omega u}$ and $\omega^2 u + \overline{\omega^2 u}$.  These three roots are distinct since rotation $\omega \ne 1$.  Since \eqref{1} is at most three roots, we're done.

To conclude, to solve for $z$, fix any root $u$ in \eqref{2}, then the first root is $2\mathrm{Re}(u)$.  Rotate $u$ by $120°$ (anti-)clockwisely to get another root $2\mathrm{Re}(\omega u)$, repeat this to get the last root $2\mathrm{Re}(\omega^2 u)$.

Remark: I used "third root of unity" in the first version of this answer since it's easier to type in words than its explicit expression.

---

Edit in response to updated question body

> Do I need $R$?

As shown by the previous section, we can solve the problem *without* introducing the modulus $$R = \sqrt{(-\frac{q}{2})^2+(\sqrt{-\Delta})^2}$$ and $$\theta = \arctan\frac{-\sqrt{-\Delta}}{-q/2}$$ of $u^3$ (or $v^3$).

Nonetheless, $R$ and $\theta$ provide a more compact expression for $u^3$ and $v^3$: $v^3 = Re^{i\theta}$ and $u^3 = Re^{-i\theta}$.  Therefore, $u = \sqrt[3]{R} e^{-i(\theta + 2k\pi)/3}$ and $v = \sqrt[3]{R} e^{i(\theta + 2m\pi)/3}$, $k,m \in \{0,1,2\}$.  The checking for $u + v \in \Bbb{R}$ is similar to the previous section, and I left this as exercise.

To litterally respond to your question, it depends on your personal choice.  Nobody can answer that for you.

- If you don't wish to overload some transcendental stuff like $\arctan$, $e$, Euler's identity, then the answer is "no".
- Otherwise, it's "yes".

> If not, is it possible to just say that $$x = u + v = \sqrt[3]{-\dfrac{q}{2} + i\sqrt{-\Delta}} + \sqrt[3]{-\dfrac{q}{2} - i\sqrt{-\Delta}}?$$

First, I suppose you mean $z = u + v$, since $x$ has never been used before.  Second, this notation for cubic root $\sqrt[3]{\cdots}$ is ambiguous unless $\Delta = 0$.  The notation $\sqrt[3]{\cdots}$ can mean any one of the tree cubic root unless the number inside the radical sign is real.

> To see this ambiguity, consider $\sqrt[3]{i}$.  One graphical way to interpret this is to trisect a right angle: $3 \times \frac\pi6 = \frac\pi2$.  However, there are two more possible visualisations: $3 \times \frac{5\pi}{6} = \frac{5\pi}{2}$ and $3 \times \frac{3\pi}{2} = \frac{9\pi}{2}$.  Therefore, the equation $z^3 = i$ has three distinct roots $e^{\pi/6}$, $e^{5\pi/6}$ and $e^{3\pi/2}$.  One way to decide which root $\sqrt[3]{i}$ should take is the choose the least nonnegative argument.  This is called the *principal root*.  [Wolfram Alpha's calculation for $\sqrt[3]{i}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cubic+root+of+(i)) adopts this definition, but that's not universally accepted according to [Wikipedia's page on $n$-th root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root) (search for *principal root* on the page to see this).  This can be explained by the observation that conjugation is not preserved by the action of taking principal root: $i$ and $-i$ are conjugate to each other, but their principal roots ($e^{\pi/6}$ and $e^{\pi/2} = i$) aren't.

This ambiguity would give rise to at most $3 \times 3 = 9$ possible candidates of $z$, but a cubic equation admits exactly three roots in $\Bbb{C}$.  Therefore, an additional condition has to be added.

> $uv = -\dfrac{p}{3}$

This condition comes from Cardano's trick
$z = u + v$, which transforms the depressed cubic equation
$z^3 + pz + q = 0$ into
$$\begin{aligned}
(u+v)^3 + p(u+v) + q &= u^3 + v^3 + 3uv(u+v) + p(u+v) + q \\
&= u^3 + v^3 + (3uv + p)(u+v) + q = 0
\end{aligned}$$

Set $3uv + p = 0$.  Since a new variable is introduced, we can add one more constraint.  This is where the $uv = -\frac{p}{3}$ from.  Then the above equation becomes
$u^3 + v^3 = -q$.  To solve for $u$ and $v$, we make use of the well-known quadratic formula on $u^3$ and $v^3$ to get \eqref{2} and \eqref{3}.

Comment: Shouldn't the $\theta$ be calculated too?

Comment: What do you mean by $\theta$?

Comment: I did not get from this part on:
so 3=3
Denote 
the third root of unity. (i.e. 3=1 but ≠1)
Since all eigenvalues of a real symmetric matrix are real, you just take +⎯⎯⎯
, +⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯ and 2+2⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯ as roots for (1).

Comment: I meant to say z and not x. Since I need eigenvalues to go ahead with other proofs, why the sum of u and its conjugates are not well posed in the quesiton?

Comment: I mean the notation $\sqrt[n]{\cdots}$ is not well-defined for non-real numbers.  It's hard to choose which one from the $n$ possible candidates.  The cause for such difficulty is because $\Bbb{C}$ is not *totally ordered* like $\Bbb{R}$. That is, you can't say "$z < w$ in $\Bbb{C}$ as in $\Bbb{R}$".  One possible choice (known as *principal $n$-th root*) from the $n$ roots is the one with *minimum argument*, but this is not universally accepted.  I'm moving to chat to avoid an overflow of comments here.

Comment: I wrote you in yesterday chat